# Netbeans not adding classes to jar

Tags: java, jar, netbeans-7

I've been experiencing troubles whit Netbeans, when I build the JAR the file is generated, however when I click the Jar it doesn't open, and I tried to open the jar to see what was the problem I found out that all the folders from my classes where empty (folders =packages right?) has anyone experienced this problem? any solution, (besides re-installing Netbeansor switching to another IDE)

Comment: try to run `java -jar path/to/your/jarFile.jar` from the command line and see if it prints any error

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: windows/MainFrame this is the error( which make sense because is not NetBeans is not generating the class files)

Answer (score 0):

At the end I solved the problem by deleting the project (not the source) and making a new one whit the same name, I' still don't know what's the problem though, but I've never had this problem while working on netbeans before, maybe because I had a Linux development enviroment (using xp right now because of requirements). And then I had a more stranger problem whit the Feel and Look, I was using Windows, and had to change to Nimbus and then back to Windows so the app could work. Such a strange day today :/